# Setting UIScrollView Background Image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview that takes up the full display size on a view. I want to set the background to a static image. I don't want to tile it, so I don't think I can use backgroundColor. Also, I don't really want it behind the scroll view (setting the scrollview to transparent) because I want bg to scroll with the scroll view.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a UIImageView that is the same size as the scroll view's content size

Answer (score 4):

Try setting a tillable image as your background color.

```
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"tileableImage.png"]];
```

Comment: `scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:imageName))`

Answer (score 0):

When we set image to scrollview as a background then that is scrolled with scrollview. So instead of setting image to background , set image to view

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bg.jpg")!)
```